# Proper use of orderBy() in Eloquent model of Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, model, eloquent, laravel-5

My query is like below.

```
DB::statement('SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len = 1000000');   

return DB::table('reports')
->select('reports.report_date',DB::raw("group_concat(reports.report_order_id) as order_id"))
->leftJoin('sources', 'reports.report_source_id', '=', 'sources.id')
->whereBetween('reports.report_date',[$date_from,$date_to]) 
->groupBy('reports.report_date')        
->orderBy('sources.id','ASC')         
->get();
```

But orderBy() clause is not working properly. If I remove `->groupBy('reports.report_date')`  , then it is working properly.

Can anyone say where is the problem ??

Comment: Missing `"` in the `concat` part!!